# Specify directory within zip file when growing archive

Tags: linux, zip

I have a file at /tmp/mylib.jar which I would like to put into the lib directory contained in myarchive.zip. I know I can use the -g option to grow the archive, but I'm not sure how to specify the directory within the archive that the file ends up in.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I've figured out how to do it is to create the same directory hierarchy before adding it to the zip file.